# Micronaut: how to replace @EventListener combined with @Singleton with @Context?

Tags: java, properties, micronaut

Let's say I have a class that is loading some events:

```
@Singleton
class EventStarter {

    @Value("${very.important.key}")
    private String key;

    public EventStarter(MyEvents events) {
        this.events = events;
    }

    private final MyEvents events;

    @EventListener
    void onApplicationEvent(ServerStartupEvent event) throws IOException {
        events.register(key);
    }
}
```

I have heard that I can refactor this code to use `@Context` annotation instead of using an `@EventListener`. I have tried to do this, but I have failed miserably.

I have another class using `@Context` annotation, which looks like this:

```
@Context
@Singleton
@Requires(property = "JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD")
public class JasyptDecryptor implements BeanInitializedEventListener<Environment> {

    public JasyptConfigurationPropertiesDecryptor(DefaultEnvironment environment, @Value("${JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD}") String encryptedPassword) {
        LOGGER.info("JasyptBootstrapDecryptor started");
        processConfigurationProperties(environment, encryptedPassword);
    }

    private void processConfigurationProperties(DefaultEnvironment environment, String encryptedPassword) {
        // unrelated code here
    }

    @Override
    public Environment onInitialized(BeanInitializingEvent<Environment> event) {
        return event.getBean();
    }
}
```

this class is implementing `BeanInitializedEventListener<Environment>`. Should I implement this somehow in my `EventStarter` class? As I understand, it should not take `Environment` as a type, but what should it be? `ServerStartupEvent`?

At some point I have reached something like this:

```
@Context
@Singleton
@Requires(property = "${very.important.key}")
class EventStarter implements BeanInitializedEventListener<ServerStartupEvent> {

    public EventStarter(MyEvents events) {
        this.events = events;
        startEvents()
    }

    private final MyEvents events;

    private void startEvents() throws IOException {
        events.register(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Environment onInitialized(BeanInitializingEvent<ServerStartupEvent> event) {
        return event.getBean();
    }
}
```

It seemed to work... partially - I got an exception just very little telling about "token", so it seems that this `${very.important.key}` was, as I presume, empty or null, so it wasn't read from `application.yml`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "I have heard that I can refactor this code to use @Context annotation instead of using an @EventListener." - There would have to be more to do it than that.  You can't replace `@EventListener` with `@Context`.

Comment: its unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish